# Issues with using phantomJs and protractor

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I am using protractor along with PhantomJs for e2e testing of my angular app.

Currently I am testing a login form. All the test work fine when I am simply checking

1. whether the form loaded correctly
2. username/password fields are empty
3. errors are displayed when you enter incorrect authentication information.

So far phantomJs and protractor have been quiet cooperative

However the below mentioned test cases simply fails all the time in protractor. I have tried various permutation and combinations but to no avail.

when the user enters correct authentication information in the login form, the angular app will change the route to dashboard section. i.e the url in the browser window would change from

```
http://localhost:12345/#/signin/
to 
http://localhost:12345/#/dashboard
```

When I run the below give test, I know that the authentication was successful  because the server logs display a success response object sent. Upon receiving this response, the angular app should have changed the route to /dashboard. However protractor fails to capture this change in route.

My test looks like below:

```
describe("SignOn Page - Performing authentication with valid credentials ",function(){
  var ptor;

  beforeEach(function(){
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.get('#/signon');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('username')).sendKeys('joe');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('password')).sendKeys('pass');
    element(by.partialButtonText('Sign In')).click();
    ptor.waitForAngular();
  });

  it("should re-direct user to dashboard page once the user enters correct authentication information",function(){
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    expect(ptor.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('dashboard');
    expect(ptor.getTitle()).toContain('dashboard');
  });


});
```

My question to this forum is, does protractor have issues changing states ? I am using ui.router in my angular application ?

Comment: Have you tried on Chrome or Firefox ? I already had phantomjs-specific issues with http requests

Comment: yes.. things work fine with chrome driver .. sort of gave up on phatomjs for the time being

Comment: That's what I thought, you can browse [the 1200+ phantomjs opened issues](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues) to find if one match your case :// good luck!

Comment: had already done that.. I saw relevant issues but no solutions and hence my question on this forum..

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with ngRouter instead of ui.router. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I was using phantomJS 1.9.x and not the 2.x

So you need to uninstall phantomjs 1.9

```
npm remove -g phantomjs
```

and install phantomJS 2.x

```
npm install -g phantomjs2
```

Hope it's also solve your issue